# How to update d3js element property outside the function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a function which generates graph based on data. Inside that, I have d3js initialized and have added onclick events to a scatter plot.

```
 function gen_graph(data) {
                    // Some other code in middle 
    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(gdata)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .on("click", function(d) {
            svg.selectAll(".dot").style("fill","#cfcfcf");
            d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
       })
    }
```

Currently in my `onclick()` I am using `d3.select(this)` to get the object and update its current value because of this I am not able to refer this outside the function gen_graph().

I have another function , lets say function `fun1()` which on some events wants to trigger `svg.on("click" ....)` . How will I access svg outside the scope of `gen_graph()` ?

Comment: I'm not able to get what you want here. External functions in the sense. What functions needs to use the onclick? If other functions want to use it. You can just add this onclick even inside of that function.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope that makes it clear. Basically I want to access svg.onclick outside the scope of gen_Graph ()

Comment: You are looking like when fun1() is fired. You want the `svg.on("click"..` to happen right?

Comment: yeah. Thats exactly what I want. One way of solving is to making the svg and d3 related variables to be global. But I would prefer not polluting the global namespace .

Comment: Write a function for on click out of the function gen_graph and call the on click function using the newly created onclick function where ever it's required. If you still face any prob. Provide a fiddle?